# Bootstrap carousel controls keep visible after click (supposed to get opacity 0)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have reworked Bootstrap carousel controls to get hidden if the carousel itself is not hovered. The problem is that if you click one of them (to go to a different slide) and move your mouse outside the .carousel container, the clicked control stays visible for some reason. Please find a live example below (just hover over the carousel, click one of the controls, and move your mouse to the code section to see what I mean):

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/bZLQRm

Carousel controls code:

```
.carousel-control {
    display: block;
    top: 50%; bottom: auto;
    width: 55px; height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: fade(black,50%);
    background-image: none !important;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .15s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);

    > .glyphicon {
        position: static;
        width: auto; height: auto;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: @font-size-base;
    }
    &:hover {
        background-color: @brand-accent;
    }
}
.carousel:hover .carousel-control {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Any ideas?

(also the right controls twitches a little when hovered, but that's another question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also set the `:focus` pseudo class the  `opacity: 0`, because the default value there is `opacity: .9;`

This is the change:

```
.carousel-control {
    display: block;
    top: 50%; bottom: auto;
    width: 55px; height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: fade(black,50%);
    background-image: none !important;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .15s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);

    > .glyphicon {
        position: static;
        width: auto; height: auto;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    &:hover {
        background-color: green;
    }
    &:focus {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqQwdG).

Comment: You are totally right! It works now, thanks! Maybe you also know why the right control twitches when the carousel is  hovered?

Comment: It is caused because of the translateY that you have there (not sure why you need it and why it happen, but this is the cause).

Comment: Was using it to center controls properly. Replaced with negative margin top. Thanks again!

Comment: Margin sounds much better :)

Comment: Margin sounds better if you know the height of the element! TranslateY was very handy in other cases.